# Problem with passing props to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `ProductList` component

```
import Title from "./Title";

class ProductList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return <Title name="Our" title="Products" />;
  }
}
```

and `Title` component which is exported and then used inside `ProductList` component.

```
class Title extends Component {
  constructor(title, name) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.name = name;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="product-title">
        {this.name} <strong>{this.title}</strong>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But I'm not able to render `title` and `name`.

Moreover, one additional question If i write that class based component to function based component we need to do it this way `function Title({ name, title })` why do we need parenthesis {} to wrap `name` and `title` there?

Comment: Remove the inialization inside `constructor`.  Props passed via parent are available at `this.props`. In your case: `this.props.name` and `this.props.title`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`props` are available inside `this.props` for class based components. You don't need a `constructor` here

```
class Title extends Component {
  render() {
    const {name, title } = this.props
    return (
      <div className="product-title">
        {name} <strong>{title}</strong>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> If i write that class based component to function based component we
>   need to do it this way `function Title({ name, title })` why do we need
>   brackets to wrap name and title there?

This is a pattern called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables

You can pass an `object` as parameter and only destructure it inside the function's body, or directly in the declaration

```
const user = {name: 'John', surname: 'Doe'}
logUser(user)

const logUser = user =>{
   const { name, surname } = user

   console.log(name, surname)
}
```

Is the equivalent of

```
const logUser = ({ name, surname }) => console.log(name, user)
```

---

Since the only argument received by a functional component is `props` you can pass it like

```
<Child foo='bar' />
```

And directly destructure the argument from `props` object

```
const Child = ({ foo }) => <span> {foo} </span>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I have one more question and you can help me if you don't mind.

Comment: Post it as another question, since this one is already solved

Comment: At least edit the question to include this in scope. I'm updating the answer

Comment: Updated the answer!

Comment: Thank you Dupocas, you have a kind spirit.